# Cannot use TEMPORARY_OUTPUT in standalone PyQGIS script

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

I have a PyQGIS script that's running perfectly fine in PyCharm but I cannot get it to work from command line. I keep getting the following error on the first processing call which turns out to be a "native:extractbyexpression" in this case.

```
  File "D:\Programs\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\gui\AlgorithmExecutor.py", line 71, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Could not create memory layer
```

Here's how I set up my environment:

```
@echo off 

set OSGEO4W_ROOT=D:\Programs\OSGeo4W64
 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\o4w_env.bat" 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\qt5_env.bat" 
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\py3_env.bat" 

set PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin;%PATH%
set PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins;%PYTHONPATH%
set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis
set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\plugins

"%PYTHONHOME%\python" %*
```

And here's how my script starts:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
from qgis.analysis import QgsNativeAlgorithms
from QNEAT3 import Qneat3Provider

from components.args import Args
from components.config import Config
from components.instances_set import InstancesSets
from components.relations_set import  RelationsSets
from components.auto_coupled import  AutoCoupled
from components.workflow import Workflow
from components import tools

# Initialize QGIS Application
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("D:/Programs/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

QgsApplication.initQgis()
QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(QgsNativeAlgorithms())

p = Qneat3Provider.Qneat3Provider()
p.loadAlgorithms()

QgsApplication.processingRegistry().addProvider(p)

...
```

The script consists of a series of geoprocessing tasks called one after another. I can't put all the code here, it's way too long and there are tons of classes involved. I'll summarize. I execute a task using this function:

`processing.run(name, params)`

I store all tasks in a json file. One task is stored as follows:

```
{
   "name": "native:extractbyexpression",
   "params": {
      "INPUT": {
         "type": "layers",
         "name": "CSD"
       },
       "EXPRESSION": "\"csduid\" IN (2482030,2481017,2482025,2482020,2482005,2482015)"
    }
}
```

The name property contains the name of the algorithm to run. The params are the parameters to the algorithm. INPUT gets replaced by a QgsVectorLayer prior to execution and "OUTPUT":"TEMPORARY_OUTPUT" is added to the parameters.

I'm really at a loss as to why this only works within PyCharm and not from the command line. I'm thinking it has to be related to the environment setup or the way I initialize the QgsApplication maybe.

Comment: What exactly does not work? Does the script manage to execute Qgs stuff before the error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote the post in a hurry last night before going to sleep. I added the error message in the post. I'm getting a _core.QgsProcessingException: Could not create memory layer